# AWS ec2 git clone or pull not working and no error message

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bitbucket, aws-security-group

I'm trying to clone a bitbucket repo in AWS ec2. But its not working. and not giving any error message.

It's only giving message is

```
Cloning into 'repo_name'...
```

I have also tried telnet command.

```
telnet bitbucket.org 443
```

But it also showing message

```
Trying 104.192.143.3...
Trying 104.192.143.1...
Trying 104.192.143.2...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

I have seen security group that has been assigned to this ec2.

**Inbound**

```
HTTP TCP 80 0.0.0.0/0
SSH TCP 22 0.0.0.0/0
```

**Outbound**

```
All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0
```

When I **ping www.google.com** its giving

```
PING www.google.com (216.58.196.68) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from kul01s09-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.196.68): icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=9.41 ms
64 bytes from kul01s09-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.196.68): icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=9.21 ms
64 bytes from kul01s09-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.196.68): icmp_seq=3 ttl=55 time=9.23 ms
64 bytes from kul01s09-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.196.68): icmp_seq=4 ttl=55 time=9.32 ms
64 bytes from kul01s09-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.196.68): icmp_seq=5 ttl=55 time=9.17 ms
64 bytes from kul01s09-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.196.68): icmp_seq=6 ttl=55 time=9.12 ms
64 bytes from kul01s09-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.196.68): icmp_seq=7 ttl=55 time=9.26 ms
64 bytes from kul01s09-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.196.68): icmp_seq=8 ttl=55 time=9.29 ms
64 bytes from kul01s09-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.196.68): icmp_seq=9 ttl=55 time=9.24 ms
64 bytes from kul01s09-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.196.68): icmp_seq=10 ttl=55 time=9.40 ms
64 bytes from kul01s09-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.196.68): icmp_seq=11 ttl=55 time=9.12 ms
64 bytes from kul01s09-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.196.68): icmp_seq=12 ttl=55 time=9.57 ms
64 bytes from kul01s09-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.196.68): icmp_seq=13 ttl=55 time=9.22 ms
64 bytes from kul01s09-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.196.68): icmp_seq=14 ttl=55 time=9.16 ms
```

Comment: can you ping google from your EC2 ?

Comment: Is the instance in a private subnet or public subnet? Can you ping www,google.com from your instance?

Comment: Yeah I can ping www,googe.com and its giving PING www.google.com (216.58.196.68) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from kul01s09-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.196.68): icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=9.41 ms
64 bytes from kul01s09-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.196.68): icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=9.21 ms

Comment: Can you telnet to google.com on port 443?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allow HTTPS in **Inbound** as it is suggested do.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Appendix_NACLs.html

Also if this does not work try using an *Elastic IP*